# Make Google Now display image with blog post listing

Tags: html, image, search, google-api

I've noticed that when my blog posts appear in Google Now, the are missing the image, unlike other blog posts:

[image: Screenshot of Google Now showing card without image]

The page referenced in the above Screenshot is:

http://thefamilybrick.com/lego-holiday-sets/wow-a-new-lego-christmas-train-coming-soon/

I've tried searching for the answer online, but I'm not sure I'm looking for the right thing...the search results have been less than helpful.

What am I missing from my code that would allow Google Now to pick up the image?

If someone could provide me with an answer or point me to the correct docs for adding whatever code is missing to the site, that would be awesome.

Comment: I am also looking for an answer to this. I noticed that you're using WordPress. Are you using any plugin or code that sets the image's meta data?

Comment: I'm using Yoast SEO, but I'm not sure that it sets image meta data. Are you?